# Substituting an operation in Z3 expression

Tags: ocaml, z3

I have a Z3 formula of the form `(> Expr1 Expr2)`, and I would like to change it by `(< Expr1 Expr2)`, while preserving the structure of `Expr1` and `Expr2`. As I understand, `substitute` is helpful to replace variables by others; but I am not sure on which arguments I should give to change the operator, if that is even possible. Is it possible with `substitute` or by another method?

I am using the OCaml bindings.

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: I don't think `substitute` will do this, as it substitutes expressions for expressions. And operators in z3 are *not* expressions. However, you should be able to access the AST corresponding to this node, and reconstruct in the way you want.

Comment: going through ast_of_expr, expr_from_ast ?

Comment: I am not very familiar with AST manipulation, could you elaborate a bit more on how to manipulate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a new expression, e.g.,

```
let ult_of_ugt ctxt exp = match Expr.get_args exp with
  | [x; y] -> BitVector.mk_ult ctxt x y
  | _ -> invalid_arg "expected two operands"
```